# How to split comma to vertical level in Notepad++

Tags: sql, formatting, notepad++

How can I take SQL code that normally is just a group of columns and list it vertically to be easier on the eyes(example below is for simplicity):

Current

```
    Select
    x.column_name, x.data_type,x.data_length,x.name,y.age,y.region
    from
```

Expected:

```
Select 
  x.column_name
, x.data_type
, x.data_length
, x.name
, y.age
, y.region
from
```

Comment: You can also try https://sqlformat.org/.

Answer (score 2):

Current Text -

[image]

1. Press ctrl + H.
2. Put comma in Find what text box.
3. Put ',\n' in Replace with text box.
4. Click on Extended radio button in Search Mode.
5. Click on Replace All.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks. This keep the comma at the end of the variable instead of before it. Any way to fix that?

Comment: @Tinkinc, Just replace `,\n` to `\n,`.

Comment: thanks. Works fairly well still some spaces between , and start of columns.

Comment: You need to adjust those spaces by placing your comma after `\n`.